# Turn off default column underlining for reports created by SSRS Report Wizard in VS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I’m using MS SQL Server Reporting Services Version 15.0.1102.675 with Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.4.6.

The reports created by the SSRS report wizard have each row underlined as shown below.

[image]

Is there anyway I can turn off or suppress the underlining?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much faster way to turn off default underlining is to highlight/select each row (Ctrl+click to select multiple rows), open the **Properties** window, and change the **BorderStyle** property to **None**

[Visual Studio Properties window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGwcI.png)

Answer (score 1):

Open each textbox properties than select from the left bar menu: border and in section Presets choose: None.

[image]

Comment: I can also make the change by editing the report's XML source code which I can  access by right clicking on the report name in Solution Explorer and choosing the "Open With XML (Text) Editor" option. This is still too labour intensive.
Do you know how to access and edit the file that SSRS uses as the template to generate the report XMLs?  I suspect it would be more efficient to edit that file than deal with each report  field individually.